# Monitor the console output from within the actionscript - flash application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am loading an as2 swf into an as3 swf. When I am debugging the as3 application (I am using flex builder as my ide) I can see the debug output from the as2 app. You can't call functions or properties of an as2 swf from within an as3 swf so I have no way of knowing what is going on within the as2 swf programmatically.

Is there a clever workaround whereby I can consume the debug output from the as2 swf from within my as3 swf? What api is flexbuilder plugging into to display the debug output? Can I use that in my as3 app?

I tried the swfBridge but ran into limitations after a week of trying. This would be a great workaround.

Answer (score 1):

How about LocalConnection? Here's an [example](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/2007/12/14/sending-data-from-avm2-to-avm1/#more-29) that may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: The problem with LocalConnection is that I am going to have more than 1 instance of the swf loaded up. I tried that and it got real buggy - locking up my browser etc. Trying to find another way.

Comment: Hate to break it to you -- swfbridge uses LocalConnection :( So the problems may be related. I was hoping that you may just avoid any SWFBridge bugs by talking to you LocalConnection directly. Anyway looks like this is a limitation of LocalConnection.

Comment: Looks like this'll be difficult -- but I'll dig some more and see if I got anything better.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but you could always use MonsterDebugger, its incredibly simple and handles multiple instances of any SWF. Its the Firebug for ActionScript/AIR apps.

It is also incredibly easy to implement, for instance

1. Import the SWC into your project
2. Add MonsterDebugger.initialize(this); into your constructor
3. Use MonsterDebugger.trace(this, 'Hello world'); to output to its console

They have a very good website as well which shows you how to use it, but generally you wouldn't need more than the above.

[Monster Debugger Official Site](http://www.monsterdebugger.com/)